# How to retrieve corresponding values from an array by comparing the other two arrays in python

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, string-comparison

I want to retrieve the values from an existing array, by comparing the strings of other two existing arrays for equality. Am storing values from `file1` and `file2` in arrays.

Note:

consider '`array1`' has list of strings `['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']` and The '`array3`' has `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` which has been taken from `file1`.
'`array2`' has list of strings `['bb', 'dd', 'aa', 'cc', 'ee']` which has been taken from `file2`.

Eg: If the value `aa` of `array2` matches with `aa` of `array1` then, `value 1` should be retrieved and stored in csv

I want to have the logic to be coded in python. Any ideas ?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "match". What is the condition for comparison? (It can't be the position, since the arrays are of different length, right?)

Comment: I want to compare each and every value of array2 with the values of array1 and if there exists similarity between the string then, it should retrieve the corresponding value from array3.

For eg: 'bb' of array2 should be compared with all values of array1 and value '2' should be retrieved. Similarly 'dd' of array2 should be compared with all values of arrray1 and so on. @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: And what is the corresponding value? Put yourself in the position of someoe who doesn't know anything about what you're trying to achieve and read your question. Then [edit] your question such that it becomes clear what you want.

Comment: I'm still not sure how it would work, because array1 and array3 have different number of elements.

Comment: Please do not post questions where you yourself have not made any effort at the code solution at all. We are not here as a community to do your work for you. :) Comparison of arrays is a reasonably simple process in any language, just use a for loop or other iteration techniques, use the iterator index to compare against both arrays. obviously, check that the index is valid for that array before you blindly use it, but you'll figure it out from there. Or post another question :)

Comment: I have already tried this logic using FuzzyWuzzy package in python. But faced issues in retrieving the values of needed array. **Refer:**[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42758943/comparing-two-csv-files-in-python-using-fuzzywuzzy-to-get-exact-match-and-retriv] in which I've posted and explained by logic with code :)  @ChrisSchaller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I understand from the question:

```
array1 = list("abcd")
array2 = list("bdace")
array3 = range(1,6)

out = []
for element in array2:
    if element in array1:
        out.append(array3[array1.index(element)])

print out
```